Ubuntu 22.04.1 No sound cards found (was working, but no longer)
So until a day or two ago sound was working fine on my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS system, either over the headphone jack or USB audio.  Now I have no sound and only the dummy device is present in the settings as a sounds output device.
I am looking for assistance in getting my sound outputs back.
Some diagnostic information:
$ uname -a
Linux snoopy 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
[sudo] password for jude: 
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 202, IOMMU group 18
    Memory at 607d1a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 607d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 18
    Memory at 607d1a8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus

I have booted into Windows and sounds seems to be working fine there so the hardware looks to be OK.
Some addition information from dmesg (not sure if it is relevant):
[    5.571290] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Direct firmware load for intel/sof-tplg/sof-tgl-es8336-dmic2ch-ssp0.tplg failed with error -2
[    5.571294] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: tplg request firmware intel/sof-tplg/sof-tgl-es8336-dmic2ch-ssp0.tplg failed err: -2
[    5.571321] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: you may need to download the firmware from https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/
[    5.571339] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to load DSP topology -2
[    5.571354] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: ASoC: error at snd_soc_component_probe on 0000:00:1f.3: -2
[    5.571382] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: ASoC: failed to instantiate card -2
[    5.571451] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: snd_soc_register_card failed: -2
[    5.571464] sof-essx8336: probe of sof-essx8336 failed with error -2


Any suggestions would be welcome.  If there's any additional information that would be helpful let me know and I will add it to the question.

@guiverc Good point.  I checked, as you recommended, and I am actually running 22.04.4 LTS.  I will update my question. Thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
